# Execute animation after .smoothScrollToPosition() finishes scrolling

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using a grid RecyclerView, if the user clicks a semi-visible item the RecyclerView scrolls to that position and then an intent is fired to open a new Activity with SharedElementTransition

The problem is that both

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapterPosition);
```

and the

```
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());
```

are executed at the same time, so the scrolling animation happens at the same time of the SharedElementTransition and it's a mess.
I want to launch the intent only when the scrolling animation has finished and the recyclerview is at rest. My code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int adapterPosition = WallHolder.this.getAdapterPosition();
        Wallpaper w = mWallAdapter.getList().get(adapterPosition);
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapterPosition);

        if(getActivity() != null){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String serialized = gson.toJson(w);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("serialized", serialized);

            myIntent.putExtra("trans_name", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(mImageView));
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    getActivity(),
                    mImageView,
                    ViewCompat.getTransitionName(mImageView));
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());}}
```